# How can ECL include ASDF dependencies in an executable?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, asdf, ecl

I have this ecl-make.lisp:

```
(asdf:oos 'asdf:compile-op :stumpwm)

(defun system-objects (system)
  (loop for component in (asdf:module-components (asdf:find-system system))
    for pathname = (asdf:component-pathname component)
    for directory = (pathname-directory pathname)
    for name = (pathname-name pathname)
    when (equal "lisp" (pathname-type pathname))
    collect (make-pathname :directory directory :type "o" :name name)))

(c:build-program "stumpwm" :lisp-files
  (concatenate 'list
    (system-objects :cl-ppcre)
    (system-objects :clx)
    (mapcar (lambda (component)
              (concatenate 'string component ".o"))
      stumpwm-system::*components*))
  :epilogue-code '(unwind-protect (stumpwm:stumpwm) (ext:quit)))
```

(`stumpwm-system::*components*` is my addition to `stumpwm.asd`,
used to generate the ASDF components in that file and the
properly-ordered list of files above.)

It simply fails:

```
... same messages you get when (system-objects ...) are
... excluded from the c:build-program [it compiles in
... this case, but of course CL-PPCRE and CLX are unavailable.]
An error occurred during initialization:
Cannot find out entry point for binary file.
```

I'm to the point where I'm only solving errors that I introduced
with previous attempts.  If you've built a program with ECL that
included dependencies, please show me how you did it.  I see how
I can punt and load the dependencies when `stumpwm` starts (even
without loading my `~/.eclrc` , which tells ASDF where to find
these).  But this *should* be possible.

Comment: related [How to distribute the asdf/quicklisp dependencies along with an ECL app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062166/how-to-distribute-the-asdf-quicklisp-dependencies-along-with-an-app-compiled-wit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, wow.  [Here's the answer](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.ecl.general/1558):

1. Delete `ecl-make.lisp` , revert changes to `stumpwm.asd`
2. `ecl -eval '(asdf:make-build :stumpwm :type :program)'`

That's it.  [ASDF doesn't see an `asdf:build-op` , however.]

EDIT: well, it also needs a prologue. [ecl-examples](http://github.com/ayrnieu/ecl-examples/tree/master) now shows off `asdf:make-build`