# How can ecl include asdf dependencies in an executable? (take 2)

Tags: lisp, dependencies, common-lisp, asdf, ecl

This question was asked and answered by ayrnieu at

[How can ECL include ASDF dependencies in an executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580083/how-can-ecl-include-asdf-dependencies-in-an-executable)

But the example code he linked to does not actually involve any dependencies.  I've tried copying the model in the stumpwm code he refers to but I can't get it to work.  He are my files.

---- ecl-test.asd ----

```
(defsystem "ecl-test"
  :description "test of asdf:make-build"
  :depends-on (:mydefs)
  :components ((:file "package")
  (:file "ecl-test" :depends-on ("package"))
  (:file "main" :depends-on ("package" "ecl-test"))
        )
)
```

---- ecl-test.lisp ----

```
    (in-package :ecl-test)

    (defun test ()
      (format t "testing...~%")

;; Note that with the next line commented out,
;; the program never uses the package "mydefs".
;;    (format t (write-to-string (mydefs:number-sequence :from 2 :to 7)))

      (format t "...done~%"))
```

---- package.lisp ----

```
(defpackage :ecl-test
  (:use :cl 
 :mydefs
 )
  (:export :test))
```

---- main.lisp ----

```
(ecl-test:test)
(ext:quit)
```

This compiles successfully (in slime):

```
CL-USER> (asdf:make-build 'ecl-test :type :program :monolithic t :epilogue-code '(ext:quit 0))

; loading system definition from /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.asd into
; #<ASDF0 package>
;;; Loading "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.asd"
;;; Compiling /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.lisp.
;;; OPTIMIZE levels: Safety=2, Space=0, Speed=3, Debug=3
;;; End of Pass 1.
;;; Note: Creating tag: "_eclitxZgyvjVscp1_KzxnJ9z" for #P"/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.o"
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc "-I/usr/include/"  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O2 -fPIC  -Dlinux -O -w -c "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.c" -o "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.o"
;;; Finished compiling /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.lisp.
;;; Note: Scanning #P"/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.o"
;;; Note: Found tag: "_eclitxZgyvjVscp1_KzxnJ9z" for /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.o
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc "-I/usr/include/"  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O2 -fPIC  -Dlinux -O -w -c "/tmp/ECLINITMs8gOO.c" -o "/tmp/ECLINITMs8gOO.o"
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc -o "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.fas" -L"/usr/lib/" "/tmp/ECLINITMs8gOO.o" "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.o"   -shared    -lecl  -lgmp -lgc -ldl  -lm 
;;; Loading "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.fas"
;;; Compiling /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.lisp.
;;; OPTIMIZE levels: Safety=2, Space=0, Speed=3, Debug=3
;;; Compiling (DEFUN TEST ...).
;;; End of Pass 1.
;;; Note: Creating tag: "_eclclGsJgWGIqMw1_y1ynJ9z" for #P"/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.o"
;;; Emitting code for TEST.
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc "-I/usr/include/"  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O2 -fPIC  -Dlinux -O -w -c "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.c" -o "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.o"
;;; Finished compiling /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.lisp.
;;; Note: Scanning #P"/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.o"
;;; Note: Found tag: "_eclclGsJgWGIqMw1_y1ynJ9z" for /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.o
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc "-I/usr/include/"  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O2 -fPIC  -Dlinux -O -w -c "/tmp/ECLINITg28qfo.c" -o "/tmp/ECLINITg28qfo.o"
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc -o "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.fas" -L"/usr/lib/" "/tmp/ECLINITg28qfo.o" "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.o"   -shared    -lecl  -lgmp -lgc -ldl  -lm 
;;; Loading "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.fas"
;;; Compiling /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.lisp.
;;; OPTIMIZE levels: Safety=2, Space=0, Speed=3, Debug=3
;;; End of Pass 1.
;;; Note: Creating tag: "_eclJi0DFzaXyAEw1_4LynJ9z" for #P"/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.o"
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc "-I/usr/include/"  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O2 -fPIC  -Dlinux -O -w -c "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.c" -o "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.o"
;;; Finished compiling /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.lisp.
;;; Note: Scanning #P"/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.o"
;;; Note: Found tag: "_eclJi0DFzaXyAEw1_4LynJ9z" for /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.o
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc "-I/usr/include/"  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O2 -fPIC  -Dlinux -O -w -c "/tmp/ECLINITeop9MY.c" -o "/tmp/ECLINITeop9MY.o"
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc -o "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.fas" -L"/usr/lib/" "/tmp/ECLINITeop9MY.o" "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.o"   -shared    -lecl  -lgmp -lgc -ldl  -lm 
;;; Note: Scanning #P"/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.o"
;;; Note: Found tag: "_eclJi0DFzaXyAEw1_4LynJ9z" for /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.o
;;; Note: Scanning #P"/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.o"
;;; Note: Found tag: "_eclclGsJgWGIqMw1_y1ynJ9z" for /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.o
;;; Note: Scanning #P"/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.o"
;;; Note: Found tag: "_eclitxZgyvjVscp1_KzxnJ9z" for /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.o
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc "-I/usr/include/"  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O2 -fPIC  -Dlinux -O -w -c "/tmp/ECLINITsLgWth.c" -o "/tmp/ECLINITsLgWth.o"
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   ar cr /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/libecl-test.a /tmp/ECLINITsLgWth.o /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/package.o /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test.o /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/main.o 
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   ranlib /home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/libecl-test.a
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc "-I/usr/include/"  -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O2 -fPIC  -Dlinux -O -w -c "/tmp/ECLINITTF1dqA.c" -o "/tmp/ECLINITTF1dqA.o"
;;; Note: Invoking external command:
;;;   gcc -o "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/ecl-test-mono" -L"/usr/lib/" "/tmp/ECLINITTF1dqA.o" "/home/dabrowsa/lisp/ecl-test/libecl-test.a"     -lecl  -lgmp -lgc -ldl  -lm #<ASDF::PROGRAM-OP NIL 38147728>
```

But executing ecl-test-mono produces an error.

```
~/lisp/ecl-test$ ./ecl-test-mono

The function ASDF::SYSTEM-REGISTERED-P is undefined.
No restarts available.

Broken at NIL.
ECL-TEST>>
```

SYSTEM-REGISTERED-P seems to be an unexported function in ASDF, I have no idea why that's popping up here, but then, I'm a newbie so what do I know.

Answer (score 1):

You're better off asking this on ecls-list.

Or try this in your call to MAKE-BUILD:

```
:prologue-code '(require :asdf)
```