# How to distribute the asdf/quicklisp dependencies along with an app compiled with Embeddable Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, quicklisp, asdf, ecl

I have tried this example [ECL repository asdf example](https://gitlab.com/embeddable-common-lisp/ecl/tree/develop/examples/asdf) , it works fine but it doesn't have any asdf dependencies. If i add

> :depends-on (#:inferior-shell)

to example.asd then *running* the compiled standalone executable *gives* this *error*:

```
Condition of type: SIMPLE-PACKAGE-ERROR
There exists no package with name "ASDF/DRIVER"
No restarts available.
```

What causes this error, and what is the idiomatic way of dealing with asdf dependencies on **ECL** ?

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: this problem is fixed for ECL newer than 16.1.3 (fixed in develop branch), so no `require' trick should be needed in the upcoming release.

In general path you have taken is correct.

Make sure, that you have required the ASDF:

```
(require 'asdf)
(find-package "ASDF/DRIVER")
```

Then "ASDF/DRIVER" package is defined. On the other hand inferior-shell requires a few other libraries (alexandria for instance), so you have to put the path to them in the ASDF central registry or use the [Quicklisp bundles](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/bundles.html).

More detailed info about building with ECL is available in its [Documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/ecl/manual/ch26s03.html).

// EDIT
After investigation it appears that ASDF has to be manually required at the program start. It is probably a bug. As a workaround add

```
:prologue-code '(require 'asdf)
```

to the (asdf:make-build …) for standalone executable. Everything works fine then.

Comment: So all those asdf libraries will have to be distributed along with the standalone exe? I'll check up the quicklisp bundles.

Comment: No, when you compile the project then everything is compiled in the executable. But obviously all the dependencies need to be accessible at the compilation time.

Comment: The thing works for me (adding this dependency).

    ecl -load readme.lisp

builds fine. FWIW I have Quicklisp in the .eclrc file so all the dependencies are accessible by ASDF.

Comment: It builds fine here too, but it won't run

Comment: How do you build your program? If you use image-op or program-op, it should just work.

Comment: I don't recommend make-build. Actually, I'd like to get rid of make-build altogether.

Comment: Fare: I build it with make-build, as it's shown in that example file. How to build it with asdf dependencies included using image-op or program-op? Can you show the steps? Thanks.

Comment: Broken documentation link, one ok is https://common-lisp.net/project/ecl/static/ecldoc/User_0027s-guide.html

Comment: @DanielKochmański looks like initializing Quicklisp in the `.eclrc` is important. I have `#-quicklisp
(let ((quicklisp-init (merge-pathnames "quicklisp/setup.lisp"
                                       (user-homedir-pathname))))
  (when (probe-file quicklisp-init)
    (load quicklisp-init)))
`